# Creación Tabla Dinámica php y sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenas Estoy realizando en PHP y sql server creación tabla dinamica tanto cabecera y información.

Hasta ahora donde he realizado es crear de forma manual la cabecera ejemplo :

```
 $tabla ="<table class='table table-bordered text-center'>";
       $tabla .="<thead>";
       $tabla .= "<tr>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Agencia</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Expediente Revisados</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Expediente Observados</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Mes</th>";
       $tabla .= "<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Porcentaje</th>";
       $tabla .="</tr>";
       $tabla .="</thead>";

       $tabla .="<tbody>";
```

Ahora en el sp donde estoy llamando desde php la tabla puede variar el nombre de cabezera y información para ello  no sabia que colocarle , ya que actualmente estoy llamando asi porque ya sabia que campos tenia mi tabla en mi base d datos

```
while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

          $tabla .="<tr>";

             $tabla .="<td>".$data["Agencia"]."</td>";
              $tabla .="<td>".$data["ob1"]."</td>";
              $tabla .="<td>".$data["ob2"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$data["MES"]."</td>";
                $tabla .="<td>".$data["Porcentaje"]."</td>";
          $tabla .="</tr>";
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
```

Pero ahora no voy saber porque la columna y data van variar dependiendo algunas y no tener con exactitud.

este es mi codigo actual.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
   /* Tu proceso de conexión, consulta y resultado */
   $sql= "EXEC Sp_DetalleObservacion 6,'','','','','','','' ";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");


   if(!$result){
       echo "Ocurrio un error en la consulta"; 
   }else{
       $tabla ="<table class='table table-bordered text-center'>";
       $tabla .="<thead>";
       $tabla .= "<tr>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Agencia</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Expediente Revisados</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Expediente Observados</th>";
       $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Mes</th>";
       $tabla .= "<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>Porcentaje</th>";
       $tabla .="</tr>";
       $tabla .="</thead>";

       $tabla .="<tbody>";
       while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

          $tabla .="<tr>";

             $tabla .="<td>".$data["Agencia"]."</td>";
              $tabla .="<td>".$data["ob1"]."</td>";
              $tabla .="<td>".$data["ob2"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$data["MES"]."</td>";
                $tabla .="<td>".$data["Porcentaje"]."</td>";
          $tabla .="</tr>";
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
       echo $tabla;
   }




?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no sabes que columnas trae tu tabla, puedes iterar sobre ellas y asi construir el HTML.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
   /* Tu proceso de conexión, consulta y resultado */
   $sql= "EXEC Sp_DetalleObservacion 6,'','','','','','','' ";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");    

   if(!$result){
       echo "Ocurrio un error en la consulta"; 
   }else{
       $tabla ="<table class='table table-bordered text-center'>";
       $tabla .="<thead>";
       $tabla .= "<tr>";
       $i = 0;
       while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          if ($i == 0) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {                
              $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>" . $key . "</th>";
            }
            $tabla .="</tr>";
            $tabla .="</thead>";

            $tabla .="<tbody>";
          } 
          $tabla .="<tr>";
          foreach($data as $key => $value) {                         
             $tabla .="<td>".$value."</td>";
          }    
          $tabla .="</tr>";
          $i++;
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
       echo $tabla;
   }       
?>
```

Comment: hermano sale un error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Comment: En que linea te sale el error?

Comment: linea 30 hermano

Comment: Faltaba un `;` despues de `$i++`

Comment: Excelente Hermano eres un maestro :D

Comment: De nada @Pierro para eso estamos.